# Is it justified to call the Event Horizon Telescope image of a black hole a photograph?

Tags: black-holes, experimental-physics, astrophysics, event-horizon

As this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_Telescope#/media/File:Black_hole_-_Messier_87_crop_max_res.jpg) is the result of processing data from an array of radio telescopes sensitive to wavelengths far away from the visible spectrum, to what extent can it be called a "photograph", or even direct empirical evidence? Can you not process data from an array of radio telescopes into whatever you want?

P.S. This question is by no means to be understood as an accusation of any sort. It is the result of my personal struggle to reconcile the tiny smattering of theoretical physics I am to any degree familiar with with the world "I live in".

Comment: FWIW, there are various questions about the EHT on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-horizon-telescope Also, https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=M87

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly The wavelength really matters. The "image" became popular because millions of people (including myself) think that this is what a black hole "looks like". What would be the vantage point from which an ideal astronaut would look at a black hole and SEE it the way it appears on the image?

Comment: If you run towards it fast enough, the radio waves the photo shows will become visible to your eyes. That seems a reasonable vantage point.

Comment: @simon at rcl Hmm... But if I run towards a cow fast enough it wouldn't look "like a cow" any more, would it?

Comment: @user1975053 "*if I run towards a cow fast enough*" - This may be unsafe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may or may not call it a photograph, as this is not a precise term.
But it is direct empirical evidence for a black hole.

In astrophysics, there are often pretty images of things, but physics is always more than meets the eye. The image is not so interesting in itself (any capable person with Photoshop is able to create such a photo), but the context and the data behind it are crucial!

"Can you not process data from an array of radio telescopes into whatever you want?"
Of course you can. But the data that was gathered has to meet certain predictions. They were not merely looking for "something ring-like in the sky". It has to be in the right place, show the right spectrum & intensity etc. The data processing is not arbitrary either but chosen such that you obtain the correct signal **only if** you are looking at a black hole.
Of course, the public doesn't get to see this kind of analysis, but the image is really just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: That is why drives me mad! Is there anything beyond what "meets the eye"? Below the tip of an iceberg is... the rest of the iceberg, for everybody to see :-) Thank you for your patience!

Comment: The Event Horizon Telescope collaboration published over 200 pages, summarizing a careful analysis of the obtained data, see First M87 Event Horizon Telescope Results I-VI here: https://arxiv.org/search/astro-ph?searchtype=author&query=Event+Horizon+Telescope+Collaboration. Looking into the first paper ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11238)) is maybe most interesting as it is the shortest summary.

Comment: Gravitational light!

Comment: @safesphere I additionally said that "the data processing is not arbitrary either". You have to make transparant what exactly you do with the data and why. The predictions and data processing have to follow from our current knowledge of physics. If you just "doctor" the data to meet your predicitons, then your data analysis is probably very wrong and other scientists will either notice immediately or be unable to repeat it. If you did it on purpose, this may mean the end of your career. It is also strongly against the scientific ethos, but it does happen sometimes.

Comment: @safesphere What do you think is meant by "processing the data"? It is certainly not processed "to match the theory". It is simply part of the data analysis. If you take a picture with a camera, the picture is "processed" (noise reduction etc.). But you wouldn't assume that this changes the content picture, because someone designed the processing such that it only improves the picture. In physics, you have to be even more careful and make transparant that your processing method does not change the content of your data. And this is the case here, too.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. But didn't I already adress that in my answer? I wrote: "The data processing is not arbitrary either but chosen such that you obtain the correct signal only if you are looking at a black hole." So, you cannot process the data into anything.